# Animation html, generated by google web desinger, is giving error when page is called via Ajax

Tags: google-web-designer

I have created animation page using google web designer. The created page is called directly, it works great. But the same page is called through Ajax, I faced below javascript error and page didn't work properly.

"**Error: DuplicateDefinitionError: a type with name 'gwd-page' is already registered
gwd_web..._min.js (line 11, col 12038)
Error: DuplicateDefinitionError: a type with name 'gwd-pagedeck' is already registered
gwd_web..._min.js (line 11, col 12038)
Error: DuplicateDefinitionError: a type with name 'gwd-metric-event' is already registered
gwd_web..._min.js (line 11, col 12038)
Error: DuplicateDefinitionError: a type with name 'gwd-image' is already registered
gwd_web..._min.js (line 11, col 12038)
TypeError: gwdAd.initAd is not a function**"

Any body help me ?